# How Can We Determine Whether an Attribute belongs to the Instance or to the Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-members, member-variables

**Intro**

In Python I want to get a list of all attributes of an object which belong to the class and not to the instance (a list of all static attributes).

---

**Some code to test potential solutions with:**

```
class Klass:

    static_var = 'static_var string'

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = 'instance_var string'

    def instance_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(*args, **kwargs):
        # can be passed almost anything and ignores it.
        pass

obj = Klass()
```

---

**Failed attempts:**

At first I tried the following:

```
def class_attrs_which_are_not_instance_attrs(obj):
    return set(set(type(obj).__dict__) - set(obj.__dict__))
```

However, `obj.__dict__` is empty, so the function is returning only `type(obj).__dict__`

Some things I noted:

`dir(type(obj))` == `dir(obj)`

`type(obj).__dict__` ⊆ `dir(type(obj))`

Comment: read about the inspect package

Comment: You simply want `vars(type(obj))` you shouldn't use `dir` it's mostly around for debugging convenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

Here is my solution:

```
def static_attributes(obj):
    """
    Generator to return a list of names and attributes which are
    class-level variables or static methods
    """
    klass = type(obj)
    for name, attribute in klass.__dict__.items():
        if not name.startswith('__') and \
                (type(attribute) in {staticmethod, classmethod} or not callable(attribute)):
            yield name, attribute

for name, attribute in static_attributes(obj):
    print(name)
```

## Output

```
static_var
static_method
```

## Discussion

- This generator function yields a list of name and attributes that are either `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, or class-level variables.
- I also filtered out those names that starts with dunder (such as `__doc__`)